# Live Comment section

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, comments, live-streaming

Hi I used this php code:

```
<?php
if (isset ($_GET['update']))
{
    echo $status;
    die ();
}
?>
```

and this javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready (function () 
            {
                var updater = setTimeout (function () 
                {
                    $('div#center2').load ('index.php', 'update=true');
                }, 5000);
            });
            </script>
```

THis does refresh the section where my comments are, but it basically deletes the comments and doesn't post any of the comments, showing a blank space. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Make one `action.php` file.

```
if (isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] == 'update_comments') {
     // echo all updated comments you want
}
```

Then in, index.php page use jquery like this,

```
var updater = setTimeout (function () {
     $.post("action.php", {action:'update_comments'}, function(data) {
          $('div#center2').html(data);
     }
}, 5000);
```

Here, in jquery second line, `action.php` is url of `action.php` file. This file can be used  for many other functions like this, by simply adding more if loops and action name to it.

Comment: Thank you for the code. I implemented this, but it still is giving me the same output. A blank. Once I load the page, which has the comments, after 5 seconds the comments all disappear again.

Comment: Instead of `echo all updated commments you want`, simply echo `testing comments`, and then check.